# Binding Exceptions slow down ListView

Tags: wpf, exception, data-binding, listview

I have bound a WPF `ListView` to a list of articles and I have that kind of binding on a certain column:

```xml
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ArticleSupplier[0].reference, Mode=OneWay}"
```

The problem is that certain articles have no `ArticleSupplier` item, so it throws an "invisible" binding exception (in the debugger output). It doesn't affect my software itself, but it really slows down the scrolling speed of my `ListView`, I have about 15000 items in it. If I remove this column binding, all is smooth again.

How can I avoid these exceptions to slow down my `ListView`?

Comment: Can we see the code related to the objects bound to the `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a [fallback-value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx).

Comment: Thank but it's still slow. Exception are not wrote in the output anymore but scrolling is still slow. I think it's still getting a null reference exception but handle it automatically with the fallbackvalue.

Comment: @Karnalta: You can create a ValueConverter that takes the list as a parameter and returns the Reference-string if any is available, otherwise it returns an empty string. Another way would be to write a wrapper (a ViewModel) for the items (as David Schmitt already wrote)

Comment: A converter was a good idea, but it's still slow. I think I was maybe wrong, it's not the exception causing my listview to be slow, but rather all the queries my binding is involving. For each Article in my DB, it also query ArticleSupplier to get children items. I should try to avoid that binding I think.

Answer (score 1):

[Exceptions are slow in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionPerformance.aspx). You have to avoid them in this case. Instead of trying to access a possibly empty list, you need to extract the right valu, or null, without throwing an exception:

```
public string FirstSupplierReference {
    get {
        var firstSupplier = ArticleSupplier.FirstOrDefault();
        return firstSupplier != null
            ? firstSupplier.reference
            : null;
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to send PropertyChanged notifications everytime ArticleSupplier[0] or its reference change.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more ? What do you mean by a "proxy hierarchy" ? Thank.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and now changed my answer appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Bind to another Property as follows:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstArticleSupplier.reference, Mode=OneWay}"
```

and in the DataContext class have a property for FirstArticleSupplier as follows:

```
public <your ArticleSupplier class> FirstArticleSupplier
{
  get { if( ArticleSupplier.Count > 0)
             return ArticleSupplier[0];
         return new <your ArticleSupplier class>;  //this will at least not know exception and return empty object instead
      } 
}
```

Comment: Thank but I think it will lead to the same performance issue. As I say in comment to David, I think that it's this kind of binding which is the problem and not the exception it may throw.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there is a significant speed difference with binding exceptions when the debugger is attached (i.e. much, much slower). Have you tried running it without the debugger attached?

Obviously better if you can avoid the exceptions entirely, but just thought I'd throw in my 2p...

Comment: Yes, I have tried the software in an independent release build, it's also slow.